# How to get average time interval ( 5 min ) or number of records using BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have time-series data, one-second granularity.
How can I calculate/transform the data to be average by time interval (example: 5 min or 1 min ) using BigQuery?
Or average by the number of records - an average of every
60 records - 1 min
300 records - 5 mins.

- row data - one sec every record.

[image]

- I need to convert 1 second per record data to average 5 min record data
  for example,  5 min average of the _iowait parameter.
  I need something like sum up 300 _iowait values (300 records is 5 minutes) and divide by 300. I am sure BigQuery has its own way how to do it.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Answer (score 7):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select 
  timestamp_seconds(5 * 60 * DIV(unix_seconds(datetime), 5 * 60)) as datetime,
  avg(_iowait) as _iowait
from `project.dataset.table`
group by datetime
-- order by datetime
```

Above is for average for each 5 minute - replace `5` with whatever number you need